# display path to files with same names

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, unix, file-management

with this command in Terminal:

```
ls -R |sort | uniq -d | sort -r
```

I can display a list of files with the same names located in the running directory and subdirectories.

But I would like to display also their paths.

I tried

```
ls -R |sort | uniq -d | sort -r | xargs mdfind -name
```

or

```
ls -R |sort | uniq -d | sort -r | xargs find . -name
```

but nothing, even if I run the commands "`mdfind -name <filename>`" or "`find . -name <filename>`" alone I got the expected result.

What can I pipe to my command in order to display the paths ?

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
find . | awk -F / '
   {t[$NF]=t[$NF] $0 ORS; c[$NF]++}
   END {for (k in t) if (c[k]>1) printf "%s", t[k]}
'
```

Notes:

- The above code processes pathnames as newline-terminated strings; pathnames with newline characters will break it.

  - To reliably handle pathnames containing newline characters, process them as null-terminated strings. To do so, change the first line of our code to `find . -print0 | awk -v RS='\0' -F / '` (not portable). `awk` will still output newline-terminated strings (useful for viewing), unless…

    - To make `awk` output null-terminated strings (useful for further reliable processing), add `-v ORS='\0'` to its options. The first line of the code will be:

      ```
      find . -print0 | awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' -F / '
      ```
- To terminate each group of pathnames with an empty line, change `printf "%s", t[k]` to `printf "%s", t[k] ORS`.
- Parsing the output of `ls` (like you did) is [not recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Parsing the output of `find` (like we did) is fine (with the caveat of newlines in pathnames).

Answer (score 0):

The post
[How can I generate a list of files with their absolute path in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux)
has multiple solutions for this problem, one of them
might suite your case.

The accepted answer by Matthew Scharley remarks
that "If you give `find` an absolute path to start with, it will print absolute paths".

You can just start the command with `find "$(pwd)"`,
then chain with the other commands.

There is also the answer by Jabir Ali, which
suggests this formulation:

```
ls -R | xargs realpath
```

Comment: Thank you for the interesting post. I am on MAC OS Terminal, and it does not have the realpath command though.

Answer (score 0):

> even if I run the commands "`mdfind -name <filename>`" or "`find . -name <filename>`" alone I got the expected result.

You're running those commands with *one* filename, while the main goal of `xargs` is to run the command with as many arguments at once as possible. So it runs `find . -name one two three four ...` which is of course not valid syntax for 'find' (it would have needed to be a separate `-name` for each, separated by an `-o`).

If your version of xargs has it, use the `-n` option, as in `xargs -n 1 find . -name`. Another option that might work is `xargs -i find . -name {}`.

---

You could also do the opposite of those commands – start with the paths, then group them up by name while retaining the original path. For example, if you have Perl available:

```
find . | perl -E '
    # gather stdin into a {name => [paths]} hashtable
    while (<>) { chomp; $name = (split"/")[-1]; push @{$items{$name}}, "$name $_"; }
    # draw the rest of the owl
    say for sort map @$_, grep scalar @$_ > 1, map $items{$_}, sort keys %items;
'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !. Adding the -n option to xargs I solved my problem. Cheers.